# How to retrive the html within an iframe through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I want to get all html content under iframe tag (all xxxx in example), if the html is like:

```
<body>
<div></div>
 ....
<div class = A>
  <div class=B>
    <div class = C> 
      <iframe class = D>
         xxxxxxx
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
html = driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='D']"))
```

I have tried like this code, is there anything wrong with this code? and the error msg is:

ErrorMessage:

```
Unable to find element with xpath
```

Comment: You need to switch to the frame first then get all element inside it

Answer (score 0):

For HTML like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Stack over flow
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This ius </p>
<iframe class='D'></iframe>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>  

<html>
<head>
<title>
Stack over flow iframe
</title>
</head>

<body>  
<p>This is 1 </p>

<p>This is 2 </p>

<p>This is 3 </p>
</body>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

You can try something like this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver   = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Users/abhishep/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

driver.get("C:\\Users\\User***\\Desktop\\Python+Selenium\\SO.html")  

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.D")))

print(driver.page_source)
source = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
print(source)
```

Comment: was this helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided as your are trying to get all html content under `<iframe>` tag logically there should be some element within the `<iframe>` with which you would desire to interact with. So first you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *frame to be available and switch to it* and then again *WebDriverWait* for the desired element to be *visible*(*interactable*) and then you can extract the entire source as follows:

```
#WebDriverWait for the desired frame to be available and switch to it
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='D']")))
#WebDriverWait for the desired element to be visible
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_desired_element")))
print(driver.page_source)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```